# Application using Invantive Web Service extremely slow at PCs with Webroot SecureAnywhere

Tags: web-services, https, invantive-web-service

Several PCs with Windows 7 and .NET 4.5.2 are using an application based upon the Invantive Web Service to access data located after the Web Service server. However, since a few months the performance is bad. 
Even switching between tabs in the user interface is slow, taking multiple seconds instead of instaneous switching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by Webroot SecureAnywhere, an anti-virus product. Invantive Web Service uses HTTPS to communicate between application and the web service servers.

Webroot SecureAnywhere does some form of deep packet inspection on HTTPS connections. The application in this case typically exchanges information in average every few seconds using a HTTPS POST with a small payload (several hundred bytes).

Webroot SecureAnywhere inspects this HTTPS POST and it takes approximately 750-1700 ms per HTTPS POST to analyze it and pass it through. Measured on an i3 processor with Windows 7.

When Webroot SecureAnywhere was disabled, response times per HTTPS POST dropped from in average 1.500 ms to 30 ms.

Long term solution is to either abandon use of Webroot SecureAnywhere or that Webroot SecureAnywhere improves their algorithm in how they do deep packet inspection on HTTPS POSTs.

Short term solution is to add entries for all approved remote sites using HTTPS to the white list of Webroot SecureAnywhere.